# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Parameter @Status has no default value.' in VB

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, parameters

Apologies if my post doesn't follow common practice/rules for coding forums as this is my second question.

I have a button that once clicked, performs a search in an MS Access database for items based on the selected values in combo boxes and adds these items to a data grid. It creates a parameter for each value and adds the relevant combo box item to that parameter.

The CreateSQLStr() function forms the SQL command text based on what combo boxes have a selected value (i.e. if a combo box doesn't have a selected value then it won't specify a condition for that field in the table but if it does it will add AND (TableField = @Parameter) onto the SQL command text).

I've tried changing the "ACTIVE" to a pre-defined string and the same error and I can't think of anything else.

My error is `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Parameter @Status has no default value.'

Details:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException
  HResult=0x80040E10
  Message=Parameter @Status has no default value.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at WindowsApplication1.frmEmployee.vehiclesearch_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\aawad\OneDrive\Documents\QHP\QHP\QHP\frmEmployee.vb:line 79
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at WindowsApplication1.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in :line 81

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    WindowsApplication1.frmEmployee.vehiclesearch_Click(Object, System.EventArgs) in frmEmployee.vb
    [External Code]
```

`

```
Private Sub vehiclesearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles VehicleSearch.Click
    If DbConnect() Then 'This fucntions returns boolean for whether or not database is connecyed
        Dim SQLcmd As New OleDbCommand
        With SQLcmd
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandText = CreateSQLStr() 'Creates command text based on selected combo box items, see below
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Make", MakeCBox.SelectedItem)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", ModelCBox.SelectedItem)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassV", ClassCBox.SelectedItem)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@VSeats", SeatsCBox.SelectedItem)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@GrBox", GrboxCBox.SelectedItem)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Branch", BranchCBox.SelectedItem)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "ACTIVE")
            Dim rs As OleDbDataReader = .ExecuteReader 'Error occurs at this point
            While rs.Read 'Adding data to data grid
                Dim make, model, year, fuel, vclass, body As String
                make = rs("VMake")
                model = rs("VModel")
                year = rs("VRegYear")
                fuel = rs("VFuel")
                vclass = rs("VClass")
                body = rs("VBody")
                VehDGrid.Rows.Add(make, model, year, fuel, vclass, body)
            End While
            rs.Close()
            cn.Close()
        End With
    Else 'Error message when no vehicle found
        MessageBox.Show("Could not find any vehicles with the selected details. ", "Find vehicle", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    End If
End Sub

Function CreateSQLStr() As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    SQLStr = "Select * FROM Vehicles WHERE (VStatus = @Status)"
    If MakeCBox.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
        SQLStr = SQLStr + " AND (VMake = @Make)"
    End If
    If ModelCBox.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
        SQLStr = SQLStr & " AND (VModel = @Model)"
    End If
    If ClassCBox.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
        SQLStr = SQLStr & " AND (VClass = @ClassV)"
    End If
    If SeatsCBox.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
        SQLStr = SQLStr & " AND (VSeats = @Seats)"
    End If
    If GrboxCBox.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
        SQLStr = SQLStr & " AND (VGearbox = @GrBox)"
    End If
    If BranchCBox.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
        SQLStr = SQLStr & " AND (BranchID = @Branch)"
    End If
    Return SQLStr
End Function
```

EDIT: reply to comment

```
 Dim rs As OleDbDataReader = SQLcmd.ExecuteReader

                While rs.Read
                    VehDGrid.Rows.Add(rs("VehicleID"), rs("VMake"), rs("VModel"), rs("VRegYear"),
                                      rs("VFuel"), rs("VClass"), rs("VBody"), rs("VSeats"),
                                      rs("VGearbox"), rs("VReg"), rs("PPDay"), rs("VColour"))
                End While
```

Comment: And what does `CreateSQLStr` return?

Comment: Could you check the database table and check the field VStatus? Are there any null values?

Comment: Also, could you move the addwithvalues(“@Status…before the others?

Comment: [OleDbCommand.Parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8), states: _The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used...Therefore, the order in which OleDbParameter objects are added to the OleDbParameterCollection must directly correspond to the position of the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text._

Comment: CreateSQLStr forms an SQL query based on whether the values in the combo boxes are selected or not. For example, if the 'Vehicle Make' combo box has a selected value (isn't null), it will add "( AND VMake = Make)" where Make is the parameter from the selected combo box value. @Gustav

Comment: The problem was the order of the parameters: they weren't in the same order as they were referred to in the SQL query. @RicardoGonzález

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop to file out the data grid.

And I would not mess if the conneciton is open or closed. All code written will have closed the connection, so code based on that assumpiton.

While the "@" name parameters for oleDB does not matter (for Access data engine), however, you might as well use them, since that code can be used in the future for sql server etc.

I would also NOT separate add where clause and THEN separate add parameters. ALWAYS add them both at the SAME time.

That way, you can change the order of the code, or even cut + paste more parts in, and it will always work. Since Access is sensitive to order of parameters, then this advice is EVEN MORE valuable (add sql, and parameters as a group in your code - not in two separate places. That way, you really can't mess up the order, since you pair this process in code.

As noted, you don't need a loop to add the rows to the data grid - it is a data aware code, and you can thus just send it the data table.

eg this:

```
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB)

        conn.Open()

        Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand("", conn)

            pAdd(cmdSQL, "VMake", MakeCBox)
            pAdd(cmdSQL, "Vmodel", ModelCBox)
            pAdd(cmdSQL, "VClass", ClassCBox)
            pAdd(cmdSQL, "VSeats", SeatsCBox)
            pAdd(cmdSQL, "VGearBox", GrboxCBox)
            pAdd(cmdSQL, "BranchID", BranchCBox)

            cmdSQL.CommandText &= " AND (VStatus = @VStatus)"
            cmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VStatus", "ACTIVE")

            cmdSQL.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Vehicles WHERE " & cmdSQL.CommandText
            Console.WriteLine(cmdSQL.CommandText)

            Dim rstData As New DataTable
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)

            If rstData.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                MsgBox("no data")
            Else
                VehDGrid.DataSource = rstData
            End If

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub

Sub pAdd(cmd As OleDbCommand, sColumn As String,  c As ComboBox)

    If c.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing AndAlso c.Text <> "" Then

        Dim sP As String = "@" & sColumn
        If cmd.CommandText <> "" Then cmd.CommandText &= " AND "
        cmd.CommandText &= "(" & sColumn & " = " & sP & ")"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(sP, c.Text)

    End If

End Sub
```

## Edit: Question about My.Settings.AccessDB

Well, be it desktop, or web based? I just used this:

Project->project properties, and then this:

[image]

So, in above, you can click on the "..." button, and that launches the connection builder. And once you save above, then the setting can be used from My.Settings."my setting name here".

So, for things like company name, perhaps a title, or whatever? You can build up and create your own settings. Once done, then these handy settings can be used in code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. I've implemented and tried to understand your code as best I could and will try to use your techniques to make it more efficient in the future. I just have a question though, what do I replace the (My.Settings.AccessDB) for my code? Is it the database path? I can't quite figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Turns out it was the database path. I've also refined some of the SQL string forming code and parameter adding because it was returning syntax errors from e.g."WHERE AND", but I've solved this. But I've had another problem: when running this code, the data table loads empty rows into the data grid based on the amount of records returned from the SQL query. So if the SQL returns 2 records from the database, I get 2 empty rows in my data grid. So all I get is a blank data grid for every search basically. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok, first up, the first question was about my.Settings. See the edit I made. As for the 2nd question, if it returns two rows, then the two rows should show just fine in the data grid. I not clear why two rows of data would be blank? This suggests that the two records in question are blank data? But then again, I fail to see how any rows of data would be returned in the first place. I good/quick check would be to put in a console.writeline(cmd.CommandText to see/ensure the sql string looks ok.

Comment: See my updated code - I changed things around a bit. The issue is are you use text or value for the combo box. Make sure you set in the property sheet the column and value settings for hte combo box. See the changed code - it had some errors before - so, keep in ind that code posted here is so called "air code" - and we have to guess a bit as to how the code would and should work. But, take a look at the code edit. The problem was the adding of the WHERE clause - it was going to fail in some cases - try the code as per above, and tweak it for your needs.

Comment: Ok, so I've tweaked a few things now and the SQL string, parameter creating and database connections etc. work fine. I changed the method of adding the data into the data grid: rather than using a data table, I used the method I was using before (see edit to original post, code added at the end for you to see) and passing the data to the data grid works just fine. So the problem must involve the data table: during the data transfer from the database to the data table or from the data table to the data grid, the data must be lost somewhere somehow. But the question is how?

Answer (score 3):

With MS Access, the order of the parameters is important not the names. I use the `?` placeholder within my SQL command when using parameters. I also specify the data type so consider using the [OleDbParameter Constructor (String, OleDbType)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46kb8y7x(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor. In my example I have used `VarChar` which you may want to change accordingly.

I would also consider implementing [Using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx):

> Managed resources are disposed of by the .NET Framework garbage collector (GC) without any extra coding on your part. You do not need a Using block for managed resources. However, you can still use a Using block to force the disposal of a managed resource instead of waiting for the garbage collector.

Lastly, if you want to conditional update the `WHERE` based on a value being selected, you should do the same for your parameters to ensure they too are not being added when they are not required:

```
If MakeCBox.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
    SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Make", MakeCBox.SelectedItem)
End If
```

This should help to ensure your SQL command is what you want it to be.

As a courtesy note it would also be good to look into taking the time to name your variables, methods, and anything else to be a bit more descriptive, for example `CreateSQLStr` becomes `GetSelectVehicleCommandString`.

Also I try to abstract away repetitive code behind a method so that you can call that and pass in parameters. It makes it a little easier to maintain and if you wanted to, you could write a unit test for those methods to ensure they do exactly what you expect them to do. These are just my thoughts. I've thrown together an example to help you on your way. Hopefully this has all been useful to you:

```vbnet
Private Sub vehiclesearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles VehicleSearch.Click
    Dim selectVehicleCommandString = "SELECT * FROM Vehicles WHERE (VStatus = @Status)"

    Using connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString),
          command As New OleDbCommand(selectVehicleCommandString, connection) 

        command.Parameters.Add(CreateParameter("@Status", OleDbType.VarChar, "ACTIVE"))

        If MakeCBox.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
            selectVehicleCommandString = AppendToWhereClause(selectVehicleCommandString, "VMake")
            command.Parameters.Add(CreateParameter("@Make", OleDbType.VarChar,MakeCBox.SelectedItem))
        End If

        If ModelCBox.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
            selectVehicleCommandString = AppendToWhereClause(selectVehicleCommandString, "VModel")
            command.Parameters.Add(CreateParameter("@Model", OleDbType.VarChar,ModelCBox.SelectedItem))
        End If

        If ClassCBox.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
            selectVehicleCommandString = AppendToWhereClause(selectVehicleCommandString, "VClass")
            command.Parameters.Add(CreateParameter("@ClassV", OleDbType.VarChar,ClassCBox.SelectedItem))
        End If

        If SeatsCBox.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
            selectVehicleCommandString = AppendToWhereClause(selectVehicleCommandString, "VSeats")
            command.Parameters.Add(CreateParameter("@VSeats", OleDbType.VarChar,SeatsCBox.SelectedItem))
        End If

        If GrboxCBox.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
            selectVehicleCommandString = AppendToWhereClause(selectVehicleCommandString, "VGearbox")
            command.Parameters.Add(CreateParameter("@GrBox", OleDbType.VarChar,GrboxCBox.SelectedItem))
        End If

        If BranchCBox.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
            selectVehicleCommandString = AppendToWhereClause(selectVehicleCommandString, "BranchID")
            command.Parameters.Add(CreateParameter("@Branch", OleDbType.VarChar,BranchCBox.SelectedItem))
        End If

        command.CommandText = selectVehicleCommandString

        connection.Open()

        Dim results As New DataTable
        results.Load(command.ExecuteReader())

        VehDGrid.DataSource = results
    End Using
End Sub

Private Function AppendToWhereClause(commandString As String, columnName As String) As String
    Return commandString + $" AND ({columnName} = ?)"
End Function

Private Function CreateParameter(parameterName As String, dataType As OleDbType, value As String)
    Dim parameter As New OleDbParameter(parameterName, dataType) With {
        .Value = value
    }
    Return parameter
End Function
```

> Please note that this code is completely untested as I haven't got the capabilities of running this against an MS Access database. if I've missed something, let me know and I'll look to correct accordingly

My attempt here is to try and give you some thoughts on how to approach the code:

1. Implement "Using" when given the opportunity
2. If conditionally appending to the `WHERE` clause if a value exists, do the same with the parameter itself
3. Provide more descriptive names to your variable names, methods, form objects
4. Remove the use of unnecessary variables and simplifying code for example, when adding rows to `VehDGrid` for example

Comment: Thank you so much your input. I've implemented and tried to understand your code as best I could and will try to use it to make it more efficient in the future. I just have a question however, is "Using" sort of a replacement for "With" and if so what are the advantages over a "With" statement? I didn't really understand much from my research. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, the use of `With` is just to simplify the syntax so you can do `With command` and then follow on with `.Parameters.Add` so you don't need to keep doing `command.Paramaters.Add`. I don't often use it as I like my code to be explicit. `Using` is there to manage the disposing of managed resources like commands and connections. By implementing `Using` it should cater for the disposing of that object after its use so you no longer need to call `.Dispose()`.